# React : How can I not put basename for only one route?

Tags: reactjs, router

I use a basename for all routes :

```
`
const history = createHistory({ basename: basename });
`
```

But I don't want to use the basename for one route (/callback) :

```
`
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/callback"/> //this one !
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
`
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks for your time and answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't the way you have it. You would need a separate history to handle that:

```
<OtherRouter history={historyWithNoBasename}>
  <Route path="/callback"/> 
</OtherRouter>
<ConnectedRouter history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
</ConnectedRouter>
```

Comment: Yeah ! I understand my mistake :D Thanks to you !

Comment: No ! This is the solution :D Don't delete your answer